# Data Structure to Query/Search from large array 10^6 size composed of objects as items in array

Tags: javascript, search, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I have a Data array. It is a big array in sense like it has 10^6 items. Array is composed of objects

```
Data =[`{title:"abcccc",id:1}`,
        {title:"abcccc",id:1},
        {title:"abcccc",id:1}..... 10^6];
```

If I use basic filter method in array the UI will be unresponsive due to parsing such a big set.

I want to know the best **approach** or **Data structure** or any **preprocessing of Array** I should use in javascript to filter my required data item from Data Array.

More Information: I am writing a search function/method where it will take the search string as argument and returns the top 3 relevant items from Data Array.

Comment: filter on the server. Filter with something that is meant to work with such large datasets, e.g. a database.

Comment: @JonasWilms I do know it is possible from the database using filters but I need to transform the data structure for better-optimized performance. Think like I have a JSON file.

Comment: its not difficult to store the contents of json file to mongodb.